# Unable to checkout files from SVN

Tags: svn

I have a 1.7GB project and trying to checkout using SVN, But getting the below error

```
RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/***/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I tried to find the solution for this widely discussed issue, but could not get the issue resolved.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: What URL are you using for the checkout? Have you talked to the administrator whether that's a valid URL? Do you need a proxy set? Do you have to be in a VPN? What SVN client are you using? What server protocol is being used? What OS are you on? We simply don't have enough information on what's going on. Please update your question with more information. Let us know what your computer is, how you're doing a checkout, and what the URL is.

Comment: how you resolved this